# A question about 'onions' in $\varepsilon$-nets on 2-dim manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, meshing

Let $(M,g)$ be an arbitrary $2$-dimensional Riemannian manifold. For the meaning of a $\varepsilon$-net on $M$ I refer to the [wikipedia-page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delone_set). When $X_{\varepsilon}\subseteq M$ is an epsilon net and $x\in X_{\varepsilon}$, let me recursively define $\text{Cl}^j(x)\subseteq X_{\varepsilon}$ as $\text{Cl}^0(x):=\{x\}$ and
$$\text{Cl}^{j+1}(x):=X_{\varepsilon}\cap\left(\bigcup_{z\in \text{Cl}^{j}(x)}B(z,2\varepsilon)\right).$$
Is it so that
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\downarrow 0}\,\,\inf_{X_{\varepsilon}}\,\,\inf_{x\in X_{\varepsilon}}\sum_{j=0}^{\lceil \text{diam}(M)/(2\varepsilon)\rceil} \frac{1}{|\text{Cl}^{j+1}(x)\setminus\text{Cl}^j(x)|}=+\infty?$$
(For the occasion, we use the unusual convention $\frac{1}{0}=0$)

(The reason why I suspect so is that the summands in the sum are expected behave like $|\text{Cl}^{j+1}(x)\setminus\text{Cl}^j(x)|=O(j)$ and the harmonic series diverges?)