# Transitive group action on mapping torus of negative Dehn twist

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology

Question: What Lie group acts transitively on the mapping torus of $ \begin{bmatrix} -1 & -1 \\ 0 & -1
 \end{bmatrix} $ (which is exactly the negative of the mapping class of a Dehn twist)?

Some background:

Let $ N_1 $ be the Heisenberg nilmanifold (the total space of the unique principal circle bundle over the two torus $ T^2 $ with Euler number $1$). The Heisenberg nilmanifold is often constructed as the quotient of the group of three by three upper triangular matrices (also known as the Heisenberg group)
$$
UT(3, \mathbb{R}) = \left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x & z\\ 0 & 1 & y\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} : x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}\right\}
$$
by the subgroup of matrices with integer entries
$$
UT(3, \mathbb{Z})=\Gamma_1 = \left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & n & k \\ 0 & 1 & m\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} : n, m, k \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}
$$
The Heisenberg Nilmanifold coincides with the mapping torus of the Dehn twist of the two torus $ T^2 $
$$
N_1\cong MT\Bigg(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1
 \end{bmatrix}\Bigg) \cong UT(3, \mathbb{R})/UT(3, \mathbb{Z})
$$
The Heisenberg Nilmanifold is double covered by the manifold $ N_2 $, the principal circle bundle over $ T^2 $ with Euler number 2. $ N_2 $ coincides with the mapping torus of two Dehn twists. $ N_2 $ can also be realized as the quotient $ UT(3, \mathbb{R}) $ by
$$
\Gamma_2 = \left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & n & \frac{k}{2} \\ 0 & 1 & m\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} : n, m, k \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}
$$
In other words
$$
N_2\cong MT\Bigg(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1
 \end{bmatrix}\Bigg) \cong UT(3, \mathbb{R})/\Gamma_2
$$
There is a third manifold, also a mapping torus of $ T^2 $, which I will call $ \mathcal{N}_1 $
$$
\mathcal{N}_1:= MT\Bigg( \begin{bmatrix} -1 & -1 \\ 0 & -1
 \end{bmatrix} \Bigg)
$$
Like the Heisenberg nilmanifold, $ \mathcal{N}_1 $ is a three manifold admitting Nil geometry and double covered by $ N_2 $. And this question

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416611/torus-bundles-and-compact-solvmanifolds

shows that every mapping torus of $ T^2 $ is a solvmanifold. Thus some solvable group $ G $ acts transitively on $ \mathcal{N}_1 $.  Despite the fact that $ \mathcal{N}_1 $ and the Heisenberg nilmanifold both admit transitive actions by solvable groups and both are three manifolds admitting Nil geometry and are double covered by $ N_2 $ it turns out that $ \mathcal{N}_1 $ is topologically distinct from the Heisenberg nilmanifold (see [Is every Nil manifold a nilmanifold?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4367670/is-every-nil-manifold-a-nilmanifold) for a justification of this fact using Seifert fibrations or for a more substantial proof arguing why in this case mapping classes which are not conjugates or inverses in the mapping class group must give distinct total spaces see here [Are these mapping tori different?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4372743/are-these-mapping-tori-different)).

Moreover it seems that even though $ UT(3, \mathbb{R}) $ acts transitively on both $ N_1 $ and $ N_2 $ it cannot on $ \mathcal{N}_1 $.

So my question is: **What group acts transitively on $ \mathcal{N}_1=MT\Bigg( \begin{bmatrix} -1 & -1 \\ 0 & -1
 \end{bmatrix} \Bigg) $ ?**